# gdb doesn't execute commands from file

Tags: linux, gdb

I'd like to execute following commands during gdb start. I've put them in file in my /root directory.

```
> cat /root/gdbst.gdb
file /root/centos-6.3-x86_64/abc
dir /root/centos-6.3-x86_64/dir/abcdir
target extended-remote 192.168.0.180:1234
```

Then I run

```
> gdb -x /root/gdbst.gdb
```

gdb is started but no command executed.
Here is what I get

```
root@ubuntu:~# gdb -x /root/gdbst.gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
(gdb)
```

And

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root  236 Jan 24 03:16 gdbst.gdb
```

Doing so from gdb command prompt

```
(gdb) source -v /root/gdbst.gdb
+file /root/centos-6.3-x86_64/abc
+dir /root/centos-6.3-x86_64/dir/abcdir
+target extended-remote 192.168.0.180:1234
```

Runnign all these commands manually do what I want: gdb sets file and dir and connects to remote gdbserver.
But why it ignores command file?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is `gdb` showing any message?

Comment: I've edited original post and inserted gdb output.   
And important to note, that all these commands are executed successfully when entered manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that problem was with remote side. gdbserver had been started, but it doesn't respond to connections as it should. So gdb executed commands silently, and last command doesn't connect to remote gdb, but silently.
Restarting gdbserver solved the problem.
But seems that it should be restarted any time I'd like to reconnect...